# Getting this error :SSLError: [SSL] PEM lib (_ssl.c:2515)

Tags: python, ssl

```
import requests
cert_file_path = "/installables/Test/icsp-python_23122015/icsp-python/icsp/cert.pem"
key_file_path = "/installables/Test/icsp-python_23122015/icsp-python/icsp/key.pem"

url = "https://10.54.200.126/rest/os-deployment-install-zips/5020001"

cert = (cert_file_path, key_file_path)
r = requests.get(url, cert=cert, verify=False)
```

Comment: Do you find the solution ? Actually, I'm confronting the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using password in your key.pem file? This will not work with requests library. You need a private key without password.